# Webpacker Error While Creating Ruby On Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, rubygems

$ rails *6.0.2* new sample_app2

```
    .
    .
    .
    Using web-console 4.0.1
    Using webdrivers 4.1.3
    Using webpacker 4.2.2
    Bundle complete! 17 Gemfile dependencies, 75 gems now installed.
    Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
             run  bundle binstubs bundler
    The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
    Skipped bundle since it already exists.
    If you want to overwrite skipped stubs, use --force.
             run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
    * bin/rake: Spring inserted
    * bin/rails: Spring inserted
           rails  webpacker:install
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `'
        3: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        2: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/yarn:23:in `'
        1: from /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:400:in `block in replace_bin_path'
    /home/emsawy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:372:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable yarn for gem yarn. yarn is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile? (Gem::Exception)
    Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
```

Also after performing

```
 Yarn not installed. Please download and install Yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/
```

I got the same result

```
   

     $ yarn -v
     [DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist
     and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist
     as soon as possible. Yarn v0.1.1 2011 Jesper Kjeldgaard
```

```
    $ ruby -v
         ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
```

```
    $ rails -v
         Rails 6.0.2.1
```

Comment: Have you tried **yarn install** command ?

Comment: So did you install yarn? as it directed you to site: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable

Comment: $ yarn install
[DEPRECATION] The trollop gem has been renamed to optimist and will no longer be supported. Please switch to optimist as soon as possible.

Comment: yes I did but still gives me the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed yarn as a gem https://rubygems.org/gems/yarn and this is wrong. 
Now you should do:

1. Uninstall this gem, `gem uninstall yarn`
2. On mac os `brew install yarn` if other platform then look here: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable
3. Check version, should be something like:

`yarn -v`

> 1.21.1

Comment: i performed these steps in user mode and got work well thanks :)

Comment: but what difference between yarn and gem yarn?

Comment: `gem yarn` is something completely different -`Yarn is a multi-process webserver written in Ruby 1.9 by Jesper Kjeldgaard.`. 
While yarn you need is a dependency manager.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error.

1. First uninstall yarn by commanding `gem uninstall yarn`.

   It will ask yn, Enter yn
2. Next run: `command gem update`
3. Finally check `yarn --version`